# Proofs By Induction Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hey I'm having some problems on these proofs.  I think Im doing right but if anyone can show me the right way to do them that would be great!

1) ∑ i=1, n of (2i) = n^2 + n

```
 2(k+1) + k^2 + k
 2k+2+k^2+k
 k^2+3k+2
   ????
```

2) ∑ i=1, n of (6i^2) = 2n^3 + 3n^2 + n

```
 6(k+1)^2 +k(2k+1)(k+1)
 (k+1)(6(k+1)+k(2k+1)
 (k+1)(2k+3)(k+2)
  ????
```

3) ∑ i=1, n of (6(i^2 + i)) = 2n(n+1)(n+2)

Comment: For the first one, you are almost done. Factor the expression and you are done.

Comment: I did that and got (k+2)(k+1), But I don't see how that is the answer

Comment: Put k+1 into the formula you are trying to prove. It should give you (k+1)(k+2). Do you understand now?